# Using specjour with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, specjour

We had specjour (0.4.1) working with our rails app (rails 3.0.12 & rspec 2.5.0 & rspec-rails 2.5.0) by using these hooks (defined in .specjour/hooks.rb):

```
Specjour::Configuration.before_test = lambda do
  Fixtures.reset_cache if defined?(Fixtures)
end

Specjour::Configuration.after_fork = lambda do
  load('Rakefile')
  Rake::Task['db:test:load'].execute
end
```

We just upgraded to rails 3.2.6 & rspec 2.10.0 & rspec-rails 2.10.1 & specjour 0.5.6. All specs pass when we run `rake spec`.

When we run specs with specjour, we are having a lot of specs failing. We worked around the [known rspec-core issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/621) by patching it to keep the configuration around (rather than resetting it). We worked around a fixture issue (a name changed). A lot of the specs that are still failing seem to be related to code that uses the Rails cache.

**Does anyone know of a version combination for rspec / rspec-rails / specjour (and/or a hook / workaround / anything) that works with rails 3.2.6?**

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

We use

```
gem "rails", "3.2.17"
gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.0"
gem "specjour", "~> 0.7.0"
```

And it's working fine for us.